# Stopping the extension to reload every time it is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am developing a Chrome extension,
It is basically a timer,
When I click the extension and start the timer it works
as soon as I close the extension popup and then open again looks like the extension page kind of reloads.
But I want my timer to keep running in the background, please advice
My manifesto file :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Study Mate",
    "description": "Using the old conccept of Pomorodo Timer study method we have this new extension for you ",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions":["activeTab"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info! you need a background.js file!

Check the docs via this link:
[Manage Events with Background Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)